# How do I access the id and label values from gremlin-python valueMap

Tags: python, gremlin

**Problem**

I am using gremlin-python and When I perform:

```
edge = g.E().valueMap(True).limit(1).toList()
```

I get, for example,

`print(edge[0])` would give
`{<T.id: 1>: 68, <T.label: 4>: 'belongsTo'....`

My own fields have string keys but for id and label fields, I do not know how to specify the keys. Supplying a string version `"<T.id: 1>"` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gremlin-python` `id` and `label` fields are keyed by T in `gremlin_python.process.traversal`

Therefore, use T.id and T.label as keys, so for example,

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T

....

edge = self.g.E().valueMap(True).toList()[0]
print(edge[T.id], edge[T.label])
```

Will provide the access to the id and the label fields' values.

**An important side note**

The element `id` value for Vertex and Edge should **generally** be treated as an opaque value by your code. Do not
assume it is an integer on all graph database platforms. For example, neo4j uses an integer and Amazon Neptune uses a string value for `id`.

Comment: It’s not always true that the ID should be treated as opaque. Some implementations allow user defined ID values which also provide a very efficient way to lookup a vertex or edge. For example, the ID of a Person vertex might be a unique membership number.